# sed exception handling of escaped characters

Tags: sed, regular-expression, escape-characters

I want to delete anything that follows a `%` to the end of the line.  Using

```
cat /tmp/foo.txt | sed 's/%.*$//'
```

works great with one exception: I want to ignore *any* escaped percent signs `\%`.  So with the following file saved as `/tmp/foo.txt`

```
abcd %123
xyz \%xyz
xyz \%xyz %123
```

the output I want is

```
abcd 
xyz \%xyz
xyz \%xyz
```

What is the appropriate regular exception handling to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the character before the percent.

```
sed 's/\([^\\]\)%.*/\1/'
```

If the previous character is not a backslash, keep that char and remove the rest.

This answer assumes that the `%` does not appear at the beginning of the line. If it does, then we need to check for it

```
sed 's/\(^\|[^\\]\)%.*/\1/'
```

Comment: The first version does what was asked. The second version doesn't seem to do anything (fails to remove any characters).

Comment: Can be simplified be GNU `sed 's/ %.*//g'`

Comment: @Costas: While he didn't include any examples that look like this, the OP's statement "I want to delete anything that follows a `%` to the end of the line" ... (with one exception) implies that he wants to change `foo%bar` to `foo`.

Comment: @PeterGrill: `sed -e 's/\([^\\]\)%.*/\1/' -e 's/^%.*//'` might be the hybrid command that you need to handle `%` at any position in the line (including the first character).